How can I find a certain string in the range, and take the value from the string below or above, relative to the one found?
Step 1 (I find the line with the desired month name):
=INDEX('Total'!$A:$L; SEARCH TERMS("*"&ВЫБОР(МЕСЯЦ(СЕГОДНЯ());"Январь";"Февраль";"Март";"Апрель";"Май";"Июнь";"Июль";"Август";"Сентябрь";"Октябрь";"Ноябрь";"Декабрь")&"*"; 'Total'!$A:$A; 0); 7)
Step 2 (Find the line with the content "RR", it will always be 3 points lower, relative to the line with the name of the month):

Step 3 (taking the value of the cell at the intersection of row and column):
=INDEX('Total'!$A:$L; SEARCH TERMS("*"&ВЫБОР(МЕСЯЦ(СЕГОДНЯ());"Январь";"Февраль";"Март";"Апрель";"Май";"Июнь";"Июль";"Август";"Сентябрь";"Октябрь";"Ноябрь";"Декабрь")&"*"; 'Total'!$A:$A; 0); 7)
